# Font-face text gets jagged on windows

Tags: css, internet-explorer, fonts, font-face

So I use font-face on a page and I can' get the edges to be smooth on IE7, IE8 and Chrome on Windows 7.

I've read that it's because of trueType and I have tried to disable it in css like most of the people on the Internet has done.

But none of these "IE fixes" seems to be working.
Do you have any idea?

Here is an demo/test page I've set up:
http://server.patrikelfstrom.se/rcane/font-face.AA/MyriadProRegular-demo.html

Comment: No font's rendering style is decided by the browser, which all user are able to change in most browsers there nothing you could do but trying to find someother method where you for example use images or flash to render your text

Comment: Windows' font rendering is a mess. The general idea with most of it is "choose your fonts on Windows", I think. Then you'll see what most people get. Many fonts don't work well on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How well web fonts are rendered depends on 5 things;

- How suitable is the design of the typeface?
- How well is the font hinted?
- From which font delivery service is it being served?
- What font size is being used?
- On what system configuration is it being viewed?

For more info: http://elliotjaystocks.com/blog/choose-your-web-fonts-wisely/

Answer (score 1):

Are you using [@font-face](http://sixrevisions.com/css/font-face-guide/) by any chance? If yes and the font is not properly designed, nothing will help. Otherwise, use antialiasing. The [best trick varies for each browser](https://gist.github.com/dalethedeveloper/1846552), but usually text-shadow does a good job across the board.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed this before.
I dont think IE anti-aliases fonts the same way as other browsers.

I gave up on font-face and start using Goolge webfonts, not had any problems since.

http://www.google.com/webfonts

Comment: Google Web Fonts *use* `@font-face`. It's just generally easier than putting it together yourself (and the selection is generally a bit more vetted for Windows).

Comment: even though this is the case i found the same font i was having trouble locally with jaggies on google, and it renders fine, so i loaded it from there instead...

Answer (score 0):

The only problems i have had with @fontface is when i haven't set font-weight and font-style. try setting them to 100 in the @fontface and then inherit in the css, then it shouldn't be a problem

Comment: Do you realise what a font-weight of 100 should mean? Ultra-thin. You're abusing the property. Get the values right (on what the font actually is) and you won't have any problems.

Answer (score -2):

Give cufon a go http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/

You have lots of options with regards to font height and dpi in there. Ive prefered to use this over font face due to the ability for it to render correctly in IE.

Comment: Yuck. Cufon should not be used any more.

Comment: Even in the opinion of the Cufon developers, I'd say. "You might also want to take this opportunity to try Typekit ... It's the easiest way to embrace standards." It's not as blatantly stated as with [sIFR](http://novemberborn.net/sifr3) - "Given that we’re well into 2011 at the time of writing, you should really think twice about deploying sIFR. ... Seriously, don’t use it. It’s unsupported software." Cufon is being kept working, but I get the strong impression that they want to shift you to @font-face but have to keep it supported because too many things depend on it.