# Font renders fuzzy and jagged when rotated on windows 7

Tags: css, windows, rendering, font-face, webfonts

http://stage.bravo-company.info/panaplast/index2.php/

link above, i realised that the font on the navigation sidebar (on the right) appears extra-thin and jagged/fuzzy when viewed on chrome/ie/ff on windows 7.

i read about the cleartype thingy, but to me the other fonts appear acceptable except for the rotated ones on the sidebar nav.

the font 'vitesse' is css embedded using font-face. but i disabled the font and used a default web font, but the problem persists.

something to do with my css syntax?
how do i fix this?

EDIT: screenshot here:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Web fonts are not smooth in all the browsers. You may have to use
>   -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased for web-kit browsers.
>
> You better use text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #GOOD-COLOR-HERE or
>   text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px rgba(COLOR-SETTINGS-HERE) and tweak the color
>   settings and shadow for the best result.

Found on another Question similar to yours. [Other Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15251399/font-looks-distorted-in-windows)

Answer (score 0):

You are still using the vitesse font:

```
$("#link-home").css("font-family")
```

returns

```
"vitessel"
```

I overrode with Arial and it works fine, looks like it's just a problem with the font maybe?

Answer (score 0):

> Web fonts are not smooth in all the browsers. You may have to use
>   -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased for web-kit browsers.
>
> You better use text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #GOOD-COLOR-HERE or
>   text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px rgba(COLOR-SETTINGS-HERE) and tweak the color
>   settings and shadow for the best result.

Found on another Question similar to yours. [Other Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15251399/font-looks-distorted-in-windows)

Also.
[This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7285061/font-face-text-gets-jagged-on-windows?rq=1)

> How well web fonts are rendered depends on 5 things;
>
> How suitable is the design of the typeface? How well is the font
>   hinted? From which font delivery service is it being served? What font
>   size is being used? On what system configuration is it being viewed?
>   For more info:
>   http://elliotjaystocks.com/blog/choose-your-web-fonts-wisely/